# RSA encryption decryption

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

I'm trying decrypt an RSA encryption system $\psi:\mathbb{Z_n}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z_n}$ where 
$n = 18721, e_1 = 43, e_2 = 7717, m^{e_1} = 12677, m^{e_2} = 14702$.

I know that the encryption works the following way:
you choose an $e$, s.t. $0 < e < \phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. Then you compute $d = \gcd(e, \phi(n))$. Then we have 
$e^{-1} = d \mod \phi(n)$.

To encrypt the message $m$ I compute:
$c = m^e \mod n$

And the decryption is done: $m = c^d \mod n$

So my question now is. Why do I need TWO encrypted messages to find $m$ (that's actually the task in my exercise)?
Can I not just find $d_1$ and $d_2$ (since I know $e_1$, $e_2$ and $n$) to decrypt $m^{e_1}$ and $m^{e_2}$?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what is the function dcg ?

Comment: I'm a little puzzled... if you want to determine what the original message $m$ was, how could you possibly do it without the encrypted version of $m$?

Comment: No $d\equiv e^{-1}\bmod \phi(n)$, and in any case you have to factor $n$ to compute $\phi(n), d_1, d_2, d$

Comment: The point of the exercise as I see it is to recover $m$ without factoring $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the two values supplied to recover $m$ without factoring $n$, in a parallel process to an extended euclidean analysis, getting modular inverses to $18721$.

All $\bmod 18721$:

$\begin{align}
m^{7717} &\equiv 14702 \\
m^{43} &\equiv 12677 \\
\implies (m^{43})^{179} \equiv m^{7697} & \equiv 907\\
m^{-7697} &\equiv 12971\\
m^{7717-7697} = m^{20} &\equiv 14702 \cdot 12971 \equiv 2555\\
\implies (m^{20})^{2} \equiv m^{40} & \equiv 13117\\
m^{-40} &\equiv 14916\\
m^{43-40} = m^{3} &\equiv 12677 \cdot 14916 \equiv 8032\\
\implies (m^{3})^{6} \equiv m^{18} & \equiv 14461\\
m^{-18} &\equiv 7651\\
m^{20-18} = m^{2} &\equiv 2555 \cdot 7651\equiv 3581\\
m^{-2} &\equiv 15532\\
m^{3-2} = \color{#FF33FF}m &\equiv 8032\cdot 15532\equiv \color{#FF33FF}{\fbox{15001 }}\\
\\\end{align}$

---

Edit: Of course there is a cleaner way to the same end... Run a normal extended Euclidean process to find [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for $7717$ and $43$:

$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & s & t & q \\ \hline
7717 & 1 & 0 &  \\
43 & 0 & 1 & 179 \\
20 & 1 & -179 & 2 \\
3 & -2 & 359 & 6 \\
2 & 13 & -2333 & 1 \\
1 & -15 & 2692 & 2 \\
\end{array}$

Then $\fbox{$1=(-15)\cdot 7717 + 2692\cdot 43$ }$, and$\bmod 18721$:

$\begin{align}
(m^{7717})^{15} &\equiv 14702^{15} \equiv 3947 \\
(m^{7717})^{-15} &\equiv 3947^{-1} \equiv 5668 \\
(m^{43})^{2692}  &\equiv 12677^{2692} \equiv 13145 \\
(m^{7717})^{-15}\cdot (m^{43})^{2692} \equiv m^{(-15)\cdot 7717 + 2692\cdot 43}\equiv \color{#FF33FF}m & \equiv 5668\cdot 13145 \equiv \color{#FF33FF}{\fbox{15001 }}\\
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

You are right with the double $15001,$ I had a typo in my first version (instead $12667$ of $12677$). Now the computation is as follows. You have $n=18721=97\times 193,\;\phi(n)=96\times 192 =18432$. Then
$$d_1 \equiv 43^{-1} \equiv 9859 \pmod {18432} $$
$$d_2 \equiv 7717^{-1} \equiv 13741 \pmod {18432} $$
$$12677^{d_1} \equiv 15001 \pmod n$$
$$14702^{d_2} \equiv 15001 \pmod n$$

Comment: If I do it the other way, with the CRT i find that m should be 15001 for both. So I don't quite see where the problem is.

Comment: Your CRT usage  makes no sense, because you want to solve $m^{e_1}=e_1, m^{e_2}=e_2$ modulo $n$.
There is the CRT/RSA variant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) but it is completely different from your definitions (and you have only one encrytpted message).

Comment: Corrected, but the statement about the CRT usage stands.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: find $k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $7717k+ 43m = 1$, which can be done as $\gcd(e_1,e_2) = \gcd(43, 7717) =1$. (Bezout identity) Follow the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Then $$m = m^1 = m^{ 7717k+ 43m } = (m^{e_2})^k (m^{e_1})^m \pmod {n}$$

where $m^{e_1} \pmod{n}$ and $m^{e_2} \pmod{n}$ have been given, and you know $k,m$ from step 1.